# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 1975 y sizes: 1 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am running this on colab, I am trying to get it to predict stock movements. I am following a tutorial and I am not very familiar with python.

```
#Imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwitiderrick/stockprice/master/NSE-TATAGLOBAL.csv'
dataset_train = pd.read_csv(url)
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].values
dataset_train.head()

#Data Normalization
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

#Incorporating Timesteps Into Data
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60, 2035):
  X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

#Creating the LSTM Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=32)

#Making Predictions on the Test Set
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwitiderrick/stockprice/master/tatatest.csv'
dataset_test = pd.read_csv(url)
real_stock_price = dataset_test.iloc[:, 1:2].values

dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train['Open'], dataset_test['Open']), axis = 0)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(60, 76):
  X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
predicted_stock_price = model.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)

#Plotting the Results
plt.plot(real_stock_price, color = 'black', label = 'TATA Stock Price')
plt.plot(predicted_stock_price, color = 'green', label = 'Predicted TATA Stock Price')
plt.title('TATA Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('TATA Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Error:

> ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: 
> x sizes: 1975 
> y sizes: 1 
> Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Comment: The problem is that `y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])` is outside the `for i in range(60, 2035)` loop, that's why it contains only 1 sample instead of 1975. You just need to fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an indentation error in your code. Please correct it as below and try running your code again:

```
for i in range(60, 2035):
  X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
  y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])  # Corrected, The indentation error
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

Output:

```
(1975, 60, 1)
(1975,)
```

Output of the entire code:

[image]